# Django suddenly gives me error that Apps aren't loaded yet

Tags: django

I am using Django3.1. All was working fine. I `pip` installed a new app and tried to run `makemigrations`. It suddenly doesn't work anymore. I get error 'Apps are not loaded yet'. I thought it was the app. Uninstalled it. Didn't work. Deleted the virtualenv directory. Created new one and installed all apps again except the last one. It didn't work. I had installed another version of Postgres and hadn't restarted my computer since then. Restarted but didn't work. Tested by running another project to make sure it was not new Postgres issue. That worked as expected.

Commented out my url confs and installed apps in the settings.py. But still the same error.

Tried multiple SO suggestion related to this error but nothing works. Can anyone please help.

Error from console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\myuser\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\myuser\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\myuser\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\myuser\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 368, in execute
    self.check()
  File "C:\Users\myuser\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 396, in check
    databases=databases,
  File "C:\Users\myuser\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\myuser\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\translation.py", line 60, in check_language_settings_consistent
    get_supported_language_variant(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "C:\Users\myuser\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\__init__.py", line 299, in get_supported_language_variant
    return _trans.get_supported_language_variant(lang_code, strict)
  File "C:\Users\myuser\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 488, in get_supported_language_variant
    if code in supported_lang_codes and check_for_language(code):
  File "C:\Users\myuser\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 451, in check_for_language
    for path in all_locale_paths()
  File "C:\Users\myuser\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 428, in all_locale_paths
    for app_config in apps.get_app_configs():
  File "C:\Users\myuser\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 145, in get_app_configs
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\Users\myuser\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 136, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the `new app` that you had installed ?

Comment: I have removed that now. It was django-notifications-hq. But removing it doesn't fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'app_name', #i hope you added app_name in settings file 
     or
    'app_name.apps.app_nameConfig' #else try this app_name is name of your app,apps is constant key word and you will  get class app_nameConfig  in apps.py file

]
```

Comment: I did that too. But didn't work. I have removed that app. No longer using it. The issue is related to something else.

Comment: I tried commenting and even removing all entries in INSTALLED_APPS but it still throws the same error. I don't know how to debug this useless error message.